# Error by sudo pip install pil on Mac 10.9.1

Tags: python, django, xcode, macos

I am trying to install PIL on Mac 10.9.1 I get an error message which I can not get to find here. I have already installed Python27, pip, DJango, now I try to install:

```
sudo pip install pil
```

The message I receive:

```
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/xxx/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this error, please?

On Xcode I have checked if Command Line Tools is installed but it doesn't appear under Xcode->preferences->Download.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a fork of PIL called [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that most probably will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for your help after installed pillow do I need to install pil again or pillow is a replace for pil?

Comment: Hi Alvaro I do accept and appreciate any help I am new with Mac I already installed pillow after LaundroMat send me his msg, however tried to install pil again but the problem is still there, therefore asked if is the replace of pil that make sure not try to install pil again. Thanks

Comment: There's no need to reinstall PIL; Pillow replaces it completely.